# Google Maps API using some high-res and some low-res Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm displaying a bunch of points on a map. Whenever I have the geo-coded Latitude and Longitude values I use those, but if I haven't pre-geocoded it then I give it the raw address and let Google geocode it on the fly.

The weird thing is that sometimes it is showing the good high-res standard marker and sometimes this weird low-res one.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

I'm not setting any options to change what the markers are. I just want it to use the standard high-res markers for everything.

Here is my code along with a couple examples of the data rows. If I have a lat/lng then I use those values as the first two columns. If not, then I just the string address in the first column, as described on the [Maps API page Data Format section](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#data-format).

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
        ["latitude","longitude","label"],
        [34.68050003,-118.15200043,"1144 W Avenue J10, Lancaster, CA 935340"],
        [33.71459961,-117.17500305,"27791 Deerskin Dr, Romoland, CA 92585"],
        [34.11920166,-116.38899994,"7359 Palomar Ave, Yucca Valley, CA 92884"],
        ...
        ["7792 Philbin Ave, Riverside, CA 92503","","7792 Philbin Ave, Riverside, CA 92503],
        ...
    ]
);

var options = {
    showTip: true,
    height: 800,
    mapType: 'normal',
    zoomLevel: 9
};

var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

map.draw(data, options);
```

How can I make sure that all of them use the standard high-res marker?

Please don't tell me how to use a custom marker. :)

I don't want to use a custom marker. I want the opposite of that. I want it to always use the standard markers on all the data points.